# Compose - Pages are reorganized multiple times when navigating with NavHost

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

The following is my code:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Host()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Host() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "a") {
        composable("a") { A() {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "NavHost: Click A")
            navController.navigate("b") {

            }
        }}
        composable("b") { B() {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "NavHost: Click B")
            navController.navigate("c"){

            }
        }}
        composable("c") { C(){
            Log.d("MainActivity", "NavHost: Click C")
            navController.navigate("d"){

            }
        }}
        composable("d") { D(){
            Log.d("MainActivity", "NavHost: Click D")
            navController.navigate("a"){

            }
        }}
    }
}

@Composable
fun A(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "NavHost: Display A page")
    Text(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .clickable(onClick = onClick), text = "A Page", textAlign = TextAlign.Center, fontSize = 30.sp)
}
@Composable
fun B(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "NavHost: Display B Page")
    Text(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .clickable(onClick = onClick), text = "B Page", textAlign = TextAlign.Center, fontSize = 30.sp)
}
@Composable
fun C(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "NavHost: Display C Page")
    Text(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .clickable(onClick = onClick), text = "C Page", textAlign = TextAlign.Center, fontSize = 30.sp)
}
@Composable
fun D(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "NavHost: Display D Page")
    Text(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .clickable(onClick = onClick), text = "D Page", textAlign = TextAlign.Center, fontSize = 30.sp)
}
```

I found that every time I clicked to jump to a new page, the new page was reorganized at least twice. When I draw a complex page, the number of reorganizations will be more, especially when using ImageVector to load an icon. This causes my page to flicker.

[The log of the simple code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPwqF.png)

How should I solve this issue? If it can't be solved, I have to use `Activity` or `Fragment` for page navigation.

I want the NavHost page to be restructured only once. Using Activity or Fragment for navigation can solve this problem, but I don't like this solution.